# Insert Text file values to database

Tags: shell-script

Requirement

I need to add text file values to database.

Below is my shell script

```
#!/bin/bash

DB_USERNAME='xxx'
DB_PASSWORD='xxxx'
DB_HOST='xxxx'
DB_PORT=xxx
DB_SERVICE='xxxx'
DB_CONNECTION=$DB_USERNAME/$DB_PASSWORD@$DB_HOST:$DB_PORT/$DB_SERVICE
echo $DB_CONNECTION
while read f1 f2 f3 f4 f5 f6 f7 f8 f9 f10 f11 f12 f13 f14 f15 f16 f17 f18 f19 f20 f21 f22 f23 f24 f25 f26 f27
do
sqlplus -s $DB_CONNECTION <<EOF
insert into GPRS_FILTER_TABLE_2 values($f1,$f2,(TO_DATE($f3,'YYYY-MM-DD HH24-MI-SS')),$f4,$f5,$f6,$f7,$f8,$f9,$f10,$f11,$f12,$f13,$f14,$f15,$f16,$f17,$f18,$f19,
$f20,$f21,$f22,$f23,$f24,$f25,$f26,$f27);


commit;
EOF
done < /home/work/test.txt

exit
```

This is test.txt file values

```
'2341212121212' '17' '2020/05/25-15-55-03' NULL NULL NULL NULL NULL NULL NULL NULL NULL NULL '33312212' 'vpn' '785' '0' NULL NULL NULL 'AUSTA' NULL '0' '39' 'ZBRCT1121300000001' 'Roaming GPRS' '223333'
```

Im getting below error

```
insert into GPRS_FILTER_TABLE_2 values('Roaming,GPRS',(TO_DATE('357217094875381','YYYY-MM-DD HH24-MI-SS')),,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,
                                                                                                           *
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-00936: missing expression
```

seems like second line from text.txt take as a new line.

Comment: there is a line break in sample data, you need 27 fields not 3. thus formating yield incorect line.

Answer (score 0):

In your script, if you replace `sqlplus -s $DB_CONNECTION` with `cat` and you'll see the problem:

```
xxx/xxxx@xxxx:xxx/xxxx
insert into GPRS_FILTER_TABLE_2 values('2341212121212','17',(TO_DATE('2020/05/25-15-55-03','YYYY-MM-DD HH24-MI-SS')),NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,'33312212','vpn','785','0',NULL,NULL,
NULL,'AUSTA',NULL,'0','39','ZBRCT1121300000001','Roaming,GPRS' '223333');
```

The `read` statement takes no account of quotes in your source data file, so `'Roaming` is a value by itself. Usually `GPRS'` would then be the next but because there are no futher variables to receive input, the last variable is given the entire remainder of the line, `GPRS' '223333'`.

There isn't an easy solution to the problem shown in your question; it's more about rearchitecting around the invariants. Ideally the data file can be changed so that you're not using the same character (a space) for delimiting values as is in your data.